# Dynamic two level list php

Tags: php, list, dynamic

I know, that this might be super easy, but probably, working late just halted my brains...
All right. Here is my PHP, which is making two level dynamic list for me. http://robertr.pastebin.com/K2XvruPr

```
<?
    $last = NULL;
    $query = "SELECT s.id AS sect_id, s.name AS sect_name, s.alias AS sect_alias, c.name AS cat_name, c.alias AS cat_alias
    FROM data_sections s, data_categories c
    WHERE s.id = c.section_id
    AND s.deleted = 0
    AND c.deleted = 0";
    echo "<ul>\n";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($list = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        if($last!=$list['sect_name']) {
            echo "<li>".$list['sect_name']."</li>\n";
            $last = $list['sect_name'];
        }
        echo "<ul>";
        echo "<li>".$list['cat_name']."</li>";
        echo "</ul>\n";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    ?>
```

Everything on view output looks nice, but source view is not like i want.
robertr.pastebin.com/J7bPQeXj (copy paste in address bar).

Could anyone help me understand, how to make those second level UL tags only once for all categories, not for each.

Thanks!

Comment: Better to copy the code into the question to shorten the path toward the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a quick **UNTESTED** fix

```
<?
$last = NULL;
$query = "SELECT s.id AS sect_id, s.name AS sect_name, s.alias AS sect_alias, c.name AS cat_name, c.alias AS cat_alias
FROM data_sections s, data_categories c
WHERE s.id = c.section_id
AND s.deleted = 0
AND c.deleted = 0";
echo "<ul>\n";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($list = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    if($last!=$list['sect_name']) {
        if ($last != null) echo "</ul>";
        echo "<li>".$list['sect_name']."</li>\n";
        $last = $list['sect_name'];
        echo "<ul>";
    }
    echo "<li>".$list['cat_name']."</li>";
}
echo "</ul>\n";
echo "</ul>";
?>
```